# How to stop ROLLBACK in progress?

Tags: mysql, rollback

How do I stop a rollback in progress. I killed a very long running INSERT INTO table1 SELECT * FROM table2 statement. I want to commit what's already there but I can't since it's rolling back.

This is a mySQL database.

Comment: Add a WHERE condition,if you sre trying to do it in segments.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It appears MySQL is doing the rollback on it's own once I killed the long running process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the correct answer is YOU CANNOT STOP A ROLLBACK. You have to let InnoDB clean up after itself.

If `table1` and `table2` are in the same database `mydb` and you want to load `table1` from `table2` in segments, use mysqldump:

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
DB=mydb
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} -t ${DB} table2 | sed 's/table2/table1/g' > TableData.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -D${DB} < TableData.sql
rm -f TableData.sql
```

or

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
DB=mydb
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} -t ${DB} table2|sed 's/table2/table1/g' |mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -D${DB}
```

That way, when you interrupt the mysqldump, everything prior to that interruption is committed.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: This won't overwrite Table1 correct? The problem is table1 over 10GB and growing. Writing to it is super slow with all the indexes. I setup Table2 to insert the new daily data. Table2 has no indexes but primary. This way both tables can be queried during day. At night I dump table2 into table1. Then truncate table1. Maybe there's a better way but that's the best way I know of. Since partitions do not work for inserts last I read.

Comment: It will not overwrite table1 because I used the `-t` option (which means `--no-create-info`). It prevents the dropping and recreating of the table. You should test this on DEV or STAGING servers to make sure of this action.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you are asking as this would fundamentally break the [Atomicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)) part of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)